# How to remove strings contained in a list in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string

How can I find words like and, or, to, a, no, with, for etc. in a sentence using VB.NET and remove them. Also where can I find all words list like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that unless you use [Regex word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) you risk falling afoul of the [Scunthorpe (Sfannythorpe) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259610/profanity-filtering-profanity-dictionaries-scunthorpe-problem-profanity-gen).

```
string pattern = @"\band\b";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern);

string input = "a band loves and its fans";

string output = re.Replace(input, "");  // a band loves  its fans
```

Notice the 'and' in 'band' is untouched.

Comment: That's the best way to do the replace.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed replace your list of words using the .Replace function (as colithium described) ...

```
myString.Replace("and", "")
```

---

**Edit:**

... but indeed, a nicer way is to use Regular Expressions (as edg suggested) to avoid replacing parts of words.

---

As your question suggests that you would like to **clean-up** a sentence to keep meaningfull words, you have to do more than just remove two- and three letter words.

What you need is a list of **stop-words**: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word

A **comma seperated list** of stop-words for the English language can be found here:
http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt

Comment: Agreed on the stop words. Widely used by search engines to discard 'unimprtant' words. Another list available here: http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

> myString.Replace("and", "")

You'd loop over your word list and have a statement like the above.  Google for a list of common English words?

[List of English 2 Letter Words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_two-letter_words)
[List of English 3 Letter Words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_three-letter_words)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the words and remove them using regular expressions.

Comment: an example or a link to an example might be more helpful